# Is something leaking from the following code

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

My app seems to be crashing on some line (console does not give exact idea). I just get Program received ERROR signal. Could you please let me know if there is some leak or other issue in the following code...I am releasing the properties in dealloc method;

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    self.curr_rep_date = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    retrievedArray = [[Shared sharedManager] books];

    NSString *urlstr_replist_curr = [[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://xyz.com", [[retrievedArray objectAtIndex:selectedIndex] BookNumber]] autorelease];
    NSData* xmlData_replist = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlstr_replist_curr] ];
    replist_rptdt_dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)PerformXMLXPathQuery(xmlData_replist, @"//XX/YY[@RD]"); 
    replist_rpttype_dict = (NSMutableDictionary *)PerformXMLXPathQuery(xmlData_replist, @"//XX/YY[@RT='A']"); 

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]  autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"YYYY"];
    NSDate *date = [NSDate date];
    int tmpCurrYearInt = [[dateFormatter stringFromDate:date] intValue];

    NSString *tmpRptDt;
    NSMutableArray *tempArrDt;

    for (NSDictionary *period in replist_rpttype_dict){
        for (NSDictionary *nodeAttributeArray in [period objectForKey:@"nodeAttributeArray"]){
            NSString *tmpAttrName = [nodeAttributeArray objectForKey:@"attributeName"];

            if ([tmpAttrName isEqualToString:@"ReportDate"]) {
                tmpRptDt = [nodeAttributeArray objectForKey:@"nodeContent"];

                tempArrDt = (NSMutableArray *)[tmpRptDt componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
                tmpYrVal = [[tempArrDt lastObject] intValue];

                if (tmpYrVal == tmpCurrYearInt) {
                    self.curr_rep_date = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", tmpRptDt];
                }
                else if (tmpYrVal == (tmpCurrYearInt-1)) {
                    self.curr_rep_date = (NSMutableString *)[tmpRptDt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tmpYrVal] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(tmpCurrYearInt-1)]];
                }
                else if (tmpYrVal == (tmpCurrYearInt-2)) {
                    self.curr_rep_date = (NSMutableString *)[tmpRptDt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tmpYrVal] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(tmpCurrYearInt-2)]];
                }
                else {
                    parse_error_str = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"Report error"];
                }

            }
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"tmpRptDt is %@, Curr Rep date is %@",tmpRptDt, self.curr_rep_date);

    [urlstr_replist_curr release];

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

In dealloc, I am releasing;

```
[parse_error_str release];
    [replist_rptdt_dict release];
    [replist_rpttype_dict release];
    [curr_rep_date release];
    [aBook release];
    [tableView release];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `curr_rep_date` property is declared as `retain` or `copy`, then this is a leak:

```
self.curr_rep_date = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
```

`+alloc` will return an instance you own, and the property is going to declare ownership as well (by sending `retain` to the array).

You should be doing:

```
self.curr_rep_date = [NSMutableString string];
```

In addition, doing things like:

```
tempArrDt = (NSMutableArray *)[tmpRptDt componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"];
```

Or

```
self.curr_rep_date = (NSMutableString *)[tmpRptDt stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",tmpYrVal] withString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(tmpCurrYearInt-1)]];
```

Are totally wrong.  Casting does not actually change the type of an object.  It just shuts up the compiler.  So `-componentsSeparatedByString:` will always return an immutable array, even if you cast it to an `NSMutableArray` (or anything else).  Pay attention to return types.

Comment: Similarly if I have a nonatomic, retain UISearchbar IBOutlet property and I use searchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 41)];

Is that also incorrect?

Comment: so i should reomvethose castings ? (NSMutableArray *) 

OR change the definitions ?

Comment: I mean can using casting cause the app to crash?

Comment: @hmthur the search bar will not leak because you're not using `self.searchBar`.  (<rant>This is why I hate dot syntax</rant>)  Yes, you should remove the casts, because they're not doing anything.  But more importantly, you should use the objects correct.

Comment: ok..I just made these updates..But still the app seems to be crashing..May be I am still doing something wrong..

Comment: @hmthur A crashing app is definitely a sign that you're doing something wrong.

Comment: You can always get a mutableCopy of an array: `[[tmpRptDt componentsSeparatedByString:@"-"] mutableCopy];`. Be aware that since this is a `copy` method, you will need to `release` it at some point.